# Create a date range

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016, date-range, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to generate a date range based on certain conditions.

My data has vendor,upc,invdate and price point.  I want to create 1 row showing vendor,upc,price point,startdate,enddate as long as the gap between 1 invdate and the next at any given vendor,upc,price point is less than 4 days.

We just recently moved to SQL Server 2016 and I'm not sure the best/easiest way to accomplish this.

[image: sample]

Thank you in advance.

Results should be:

```
183020   2840000211 1.47  12/23/16 - 12/26/16
183020   2840000211 1.39  12/31/16 - 01/03/17
183020   2840000211 1.39  01/09/17 - 01/16/17
```

Comment: show sample data

Comment: put it in  question and select all press CTRL+K

Comment: What if the price changed but the datediff is less than 4 days.

Comment: Do not post sample data as images. Provide it as text.

Comment: if the price changes OR there's a gap of more than 4 days i need a new line.

Comment: Hi Joel, usually your reporting tool like SSRS takes care of that request (to break it into a new line). The best you can do is use LAG to determine the previous record's inv_date and compare previous to current inv_date to determine if it's greater or equal to 4, which SSRS can then use and break out to a new row, including do nice groupings etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) scenario where each record in the desired output represents an island (where `net_cost` does not change and you have `inv_date` snapshots confirming it less than 4 days after the previous one). The gaps are the `net_cost` / `inv_date` values not represented (e.g. we don't know what the `net_cost` was on the `inv_date` of `2016-12-27` through `2016-12-30`).

The query below does three things:

1. Identifies the gaps (column `is_gap_start`) by checking to see if
   there are violations of the 2 constraints laid out in the question (change in
   `net_cost` or gap of 4 days or more of `inv_date` values)
2. Assigns the island number (column `island_nbr`) making use of a running total of the gaps encountered.
3. Determines the values to display for each island in the final result

**Answer:**

```
select b.vnd_nbr
, b.upc_nbr
, b.net_cost
, min(b.inv_date) as inv_date_bgn
, max(b.inv_date) as inv_date_end
from (
    select a.vnd_nbr
    , a.upc_nbr
    , a.inv_date
    , a.net_cost
    --determine the island number
    , sum(a.is_gap_start) over (partition by a.vnd_nbr, a.upc_nbr order by a.inv_date asc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as island_nbr
    from (
        select t.vnd_nbr
        , t.upc_nbr
        , t.inv_date
        , t.net_cost
        --check if the next row meets either condition to start new date range (4 day gap, change in net_cost)
        , case when datediff(d, t.inv_date, lead(t.inv_date, 1, t.inv_date) over (partition by t.vnd_nbr, t.upc_nbr order by t.inv_date asc)) >= 4 
                    or t.net_cost <> lead(t.net_cost, 1, t.net_cost) over (partition by t.vnd_nbr, t.upc_nbr order by t.inv_date asc)
            then 1 
            else 0 
            end as is_gap_start
        from data_table as t
        ) as a
    ) as b
group by b.vnd_nbr
, b.upc_nbr
, b.net_cost
, isnull(b.island_nbr, 0) --forces each island to be a separate row
order by b.vnd_nbr
, b.upc_nbr
, isnull(b.island_nbr, 0)
```

**Results:**

```
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+
| vnd_nbr |  upc_nbr   | net_cost | inv_date_bgn | inv_date_end |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+
|  183020 | 2840000211 | 1.47     | 2016-12-23   | 2016-12-26   |
|  183020 | 2840000211 | 1.39     | 2016-12-31   | 2017-01-03   |
|  183020 | 2840000211 | 1.39     | 2017-01-09   | 2017-01-16   |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: wow thanks! this is actually very useful to learn, my answer feels so wrong now! lol

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with and DOES NOT SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM EXACTLY, but I feel like I could post this code to at least have you work out the rest and perhaps get to an answer you can work with (keeping in mind my comment)

```
DECLARE @TableVar TABLE 
  ( 
     vnd_nbr  INT, 
     upc_nbr  VARCHAR(10), 
     inv_date DATE, 
     net_cost DECIMAL(16, 2) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @TableVar 
            (vnd_nbr, 
             upc_nbr, 
             inv_date, 
             net_cost) 
VALUES      (183020, 
             '2840000211', 
             '23-Dec-2016', 
             1.47), 
            (183020, 
             '2840000211', 
             '26-Dec-2016', 
             1.47), 
            (183020, 
             '2840000211', 
             '31-Dec-2016', 
             1.39), 
            (183020, 
             '2840000211', 
             '2-Jan-2017', 
             1.39), 
            (183020, 
             '2840000211', 
             '3-Jan-2017', 
             1.39), 
            (183020, 
             '2840000211', 
             '09-Jan-2017', 
             1.39), 
            (183020, 
             '2840000211', 
             '12-Jan-2017', 
             1.39), 
            (183020, 
             '2840000211', 
             '13-Jan-2017', 
             1.39), 
            (183020, 
             '2840000211', 
             '14-Jan-2017', 
             1.39), 
            (183020, 
             '2840000211', 
             '16-Jan-2017', 
             1.39) 

SELECT vnd_nbr, 
       upc_nbr, 
       net_cost, 
       Min(Isnull(previous_date, inv_date)) AS StartDate, 
       Max(inv_date)                        AS EndDate 
FROM   (SELECT vnd_nbr, 
               upc_nbr, 
               inv_date, 
               net_cost, 
               previous_date, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Datediff(day, Isnull(previous_date, inv_date), inv_date) < 
                      4 THEN 
                 0 
                 ELSE 1 
               END GreaterThanFourDays 
        FROM   (SELECT vnd_nbr, 
                       upc_nbr, 
                       inv_date, 
                       net_cost, 
                       Lag(inv_date, 1, NULL) 
                         OVER ( 
                           partition BY vnd_nbr, upc_nbr, net_cost 
                           ORDER BY inv_date) AS previous_date 
                FROM   @TableVar) r) rr 
GROUP  BY greaterthanfourdays, 
          vnd_nbr, 
          upc_nbr, 
          net_cost 
ORDER  BY Min(inv_date)
```

The above outputs this:

```
vnd_nbr upc_nbr net_cost    StartDate   EndDate
183020  2840000211  1.47    2016-12-23  2016-12-26
183020  2840000211  1.39    2016-12-31  2017-01-16
183020  2840000211  1.39    2017-01-03  2017-01-09
```

The start/end date doesn't match but it breaks it up if greater than 4 days / takes into consideration net_cost.

Like I said, it doesn't solve your issue exactly, but it gives you an idea of how you can do what you ask.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll see if I can make this work for what I need.